# Print only the matched characters in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a Perl one-liner if I want to print only the matched characters with Perl. For example I have a text file like this:

```
data.txt
foo1 bar baz
foo2 bar baz
bar foo3 baz
bar baz foo4
```

I tried the following but there was no output:

```
perl -ne '/foo\d/ && print "$1"' data.txt
```

Comment: `$1` references a Capture Group. Try wrapping the pattern for your desired output in parenthesis to make it a capture group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$1` contains the part that was matched by the first capture group, but you have no capture groups in your regexp.

Use `$&` to get everything matched by the whole pattern.

```
perl -ne '/foo\d/ && print "$&"' data.txt
```